# Hasse diagram for the relation $\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,b),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c)\}$ on set $M=\{a,b,c\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

> Hasse diagram for the the relation $\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,b),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c)\}$ on set $M=\{a,b,c\}$

I tried to make the Hasse-Diagram for the relation. But as every element is in relation to all other elements, there can be no edges between the elements in the Hasse-diagram. Is this right or am I wrong? Would the Hasse-diagram then simply be $c, b, a$ without edges?

Comment: Hasse diagrams are ways of picturing Posets, partially ordered sets, a set and a relation where the relation is a partial order, that is a relation which is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric.  Your relation is an equivalence relation and not a partial order.  It does not qualify for a Hasse diagram.  You may draw a graph for it anyways, for instance as a $K_3$ with loops on every vertex, but that is not a Hasse diagram.

Comment: Why is it antisymmetric? I thought it's symmetric

Comment: "*Why is* **it** *antisymmetric?*"  What "it" are you referring to here?  Your relation?  Your relation is symmetric.  A partial order?  Why is a partial order antisymmetric?  Because that is a part of the definition of what it means to be a partial order in the first place...

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I thought you said the relation that was given is antisymmetric which is not true. I just noticed that you meant the partial order. Thank you!

Comment: @JMoravitz which elements from the set would I have to remove to make it a partial order?

Comment: ... there are only a few partial orders on three elements.  You have the ones where they all appear in a chain like $a<b<c$ and you have others where you have some but not all are comparable like $a<c, b<c$ but $a$ and $b$ are not comparable... and then you have where none are comparable at all.  If you insist on talking about "removing some elements to make it a partial order"... you need to make it antisymmetric, so removing at least one of $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$ for each $x\neq y$ in your set, and then ensure that it was still transitive afterwards.  $a<b<c<a$ for instance doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, would $\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,b),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c)\}$ be a correct example of a subset that is a partial order (removed ba)?

Comment: **for each** $x\neq y$.  No.  That is still not a partial order... you have both $(a,c)$ and $(c,a)$.  At least one of those needs to go away.  You have $(b,c)$ and $(c,b)$, at least one of those needs to go away...

Comment: I'm sry, it's late already. I overlooked the words "for each". So it should be $\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,b),(b,c),(c,c)\}$, right? If I think about it, it makes perfect sense because otherwise antisymmetric.

Comment: That is one example of many, yes, and corresponds to $a<b<c$ whose Hasse diagram is just a vertex labeled $c$ at the top with a line straight down connecting it to a vertex labeled $b$ with a line straight down from that connecting it to a vertex labeled $a$.

Comment: Thank you. Why is $c$ on top?

Comment: Because that is how a Hasse diagram is drawn... If $x<y$ then $y$ is drawn above $x$... $y$ is "greater" than $x$ and so receives greater height in the diagram.  It just so happens here that in your example you had $c$ was greater than both $a$ and $b$ and so was drawn at the top.  If we were to look instead at $c<a<b$ then it would have been $b$ at the top, $a$ in the middle and $c$ at the bottom.

Comment: This is really easier than I thought. Thank you and sorry for those dumb questions

Comment: @JMoravitz how many different partial orders are there in total? I would like to know if I have found all of them.

Comment: In general, counting the number of posets is quite involved. For this, since there are so few we can do it by brute force. There are six of the form a<b<c where all are comparable. There are 3 where one is bigger than the other two with those other two incomparable. Similarly with one smaller than other two. Then you have six where one is completely incomparable and the other two are. Finally one where all are incomparable to all. By my count then we have $6+3+3+6+1=19$ posets on a,b,c

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A001035

Answer (score 0):

The only Hasse diagrams I'm familiar with are the diagrams of an order $<$. In other words, the diagram is of an antisymmetric relation.